# Create elements and querySelector doesn't work in VueJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I had created HTML elements using Javascript. When I tried to transform the codes into VueJS, the elements are not created when page load.

**HTML**

```
<div id="chat" class="chat-size col-centered margin-btm-50"></div>
```

**VueJS**

```
var chatSample = [
   {name:"Julia", message: "Hi"},
   {name:"John", message: "Hi"},
   {name:"Julia", message: "Bye"}
];

chatSample.forEach(function (obj, i) {
  var rowItem = document.createElement('div')
  var chatItem = document.createElement('div')
  var chatName = document.createElement('div')
  var msg = document.createTextNode(obj.message)
  var name = document.createTextNode(obj.name)
  rowItem.className = 'chat-row margin-chat none'
  if (i === chatSample.length - 1) {
    rowItem.id = 'last'
  }
  if (obj.name === 'Police') {
    chatItem.className = 'chat-right'
    chatName.className = 'name bold text-right padding-chat-right'
  } else {
    chatItem.className = 'chat-left'
    chatName.className = 'name text-left padding-chat-left'
  }
  chatItem.innerHTML = msg.textContent
  chatName.innerHTML = name.textContent
  var chat = document.querySelector('#chat');
  rowItem.appendChild(chatName);
  rowItem.appendChild(chatItem);
});
```

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vjvMp/2070/

Comment: There is 1 issue. In this: `if (i === chatSample.length - 1)`, what is `chatSample`? If you are referring to object above, you should pass it as argument and access it. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjvMp/2079/). Note, I'm not a vue person, so just fixed JS part.

Answer (score 0):

Vue uses declarative rendering to show data. It has a templating system that is very straightforward and I recommend you read this - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

This link will then help you in rendering your list - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it the VueJS way. For instance

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    chatSample: [{
        'name': '<b>Chuan</b> | Male | 30 | Subang Jaya',
        'message': 'Who is there?'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Police',
        'message': 'Police '
      },
      {
        'name': '<b>Chuan</b> | Male | 30 | Subang Jaya',
        'message': 'What do you want?'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Police',
        'message': 'We want to talk.'
      },
      {
        'name': '<b>Chuan</b> | Male | 30 | Subang Jaya',
        'message': 'How many of you are there?'
      },
      {
        'name': '<b>Chuan</b> | Male | 30 | Subang Jaya',
        'message': 'How many of you are there?'
      },
      {
        'name': '<b>Chuan</b> | Male | 30 | Subang Jaya',
        'message': 'How many of you are there?'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Police',
        'message': 'Two.'
      },
      {
        'name': '<b>Chuan</b> | Male | 30 | Subang Jaya',
        'message': 'So talk with each other'
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <div class="chat-size col-centered margin-btm-50">
    <div class="row chat-row margin-chat none" v-for="(chat, idx) in chatSample" :key="idx">
      <div class="name text-left padding-chat-left" v-html="chat.name"></div>
      <div class="chat-left" v-html="chat.message"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
```

You can add conditional classes using `:class` attribute from Vue.